# Is it possible to read files with uncommon extensions (not like .txt or .csv) in Apache Beam using Python SDK? For example, file with .set extension

Tags: apache-beam

Is it possible to read files with uncommon extensions (not like .txt or .csv or .json) in Apache Beam using Python SDK? For example, I want to read file from local with .set extension (this is special file with EEG record). I could't find any information about how to implement this on the official page.

If I understand correctly, beam.Create creates PCollection from iterable, but what if my data is not iterable (like data in .set file)? How to read it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one file to process, you can pass a list to beam.Create that contains your set file.

```
p | 'Initialise pipeline' >> beam.Create(['your_file.set'])
```

Regarding reading the set file, even if it's not supported officially by beam I/O connectors, you can create your own connector with python

```
class ReadSetContent(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, file):

        # your set file path will passed here, so you can read it
        # yield the content of the set file and it will be processed by the net transformation
```

So you pipeline start would look like this

```
(p | 'Initialise pipeline' >> beam.Create(['your_file.set'])
  | 'Reading content' >> beam.ParDo(ReadSetContent())
  | 'Next transformation' >> ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Beam [fileio](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py) library to read arbitrary files. Any custom processing should be done by subsequent [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) transforms.